# dojo component not parsed after jquery reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dojo

Everyone. The current project I am working on requires a DOJO tabbed paned to hold data from DB and it requires to refresh part of the page (a div with id "refreshable" which inludes the tabbed pane div) to keep the data in the tabbed pane up-to-date.

The problem here is when I call the following method with firebugs

```
j('#refreshable').load(url+' #refreshable > *', function (response) {
    console.log("hello");
    dojo.parser.parse(Dojo.byId('tabbedPane'));
    console.log("hello again !");
});
```

It appears that in firebug console only show up "hello" but no "hello again !" without any error message. It seems the call for Dojo parser is broken in the jquery reload function.

Then the consequence is each time the 'refreshable' get refreshed then all the tables in the tabbed pane show up on a stack -- Dojo parser failed.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance !.

Comment: What does your error console say? You should get some kind of JS error if its failing.

Comment: Thanks for quick feedback prodigitalson. Actually there is no error message, which is strange, the only thing I can see is "Hello" and all the html code in 'response' from console tab. Also no error from script tab and net tab as well...strange...

Comment: wierd... do a `console.log([dojo, Dojo]);` just after you `'hello'` log and see if either of those array items come back `undefined`;

Comment: Thank you prodigitalson. No information show up on the console log. Even I place "console.log([dojo, Dojo]);" before the hello dummy message, then there is no "hello" message show up on the console.

Comment: Oh, and by the way in firebug 'Script' tag -> "Inline" I can see the dojo.js is enlisted. So seems the dojo library is found but some of the function conflicts with jquery?

Comment: if youre not seeing anything on the console at that point then either the request is failing and thus your success handler is never running or something else is causing an error and halting script execution before that is executed.

Comment: are you using `dojo.require` or are you manually putting the script tag in the `head` yourself?

Comment: Thank you. There is a line in the header 'dojo.require("dojo.parser");'. Also I place djConfig="parseOnLoad: true" before that. So may be that is not enough to keep things working? The tabbed pane does look good before the reload. But after then dojo parser becomes cripple...

Comment: Are you sure your dojo is named Dojo with a capital D?  Sounds to me like the issue is you're hitting a JS error that dojo.parser.parse is suppressing since Dojo is undefined.

Comment: Hi, Kevin. Thank you for the reply. Could you please be more specific where I should use a capital 'Dojo' in the code? Actually I place the small "d" to every dojo component and every dojo call. But can it be a problem? I am newbie to dojo but I saw quite a few code using lower case 'dojo' calls. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Kevin For example, from [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/layout/TabContainer.html) the small case dojo call is all around the place so may be I miss the capital Dojo somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was referring to your snippet :
    dojo.parser.parse(Dojo.byId('tabbedPane'));

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that are wrong here:
1) uppercase "Dojo". dojo is always lowercase, period.
2) you're "holding it wrong". You need to grasp the concept of instances of widgets and their lifecycle.

Seems you are using an old pre-AMD (1.7? or so) version of dojo, because otherwise dojo would not be exported as a global variable.

If it's a newer version, you have to look at the docs for newer versions.

So what does your dojo snippet do:

dojo.byId('foo') returns you a reference to a given domNode, but it's ID attribute.
dojo.parser.parse(node) parses a node, looking for data-dojo-type or dojo-type attributes on it, and instantiates an according widget on it.

If you parse that multiple times, you will get all sorts of errors, because you're doing something you shouldnt:

Trying to re-parse an already instantiated widget.

You can't re-parse an already instantiated dojo widget.
Even if you cleared the dom and reset it, you're leaking an instance in the widget registry.

You must destroy it first.

To do so, in pseudo-code:

```
require(['dijit/_base/registry'], function(registry){
 registry.byNode(document.getElementById('tabbedPane'))[0].destroy();
})
```

This snippet is asyncronous, because it uses require.
If you use non-amd dojo, you can simply do `dijit.byNode(document.getElementById('tabbedPane'))[0].destroy();`